# How to move TitledPane and not Stage during mouse drag event

Tags: javafx

I would like to make a JavaFX titled pane draggable, but when I click and drag the titled pane the whole application moves instead leaving a black background. I know that I'm referencing the stage, but I can't work out how to target the titled pane. Thank you in advance.

```
@FXML
private TitledPane CallRequestTitledPane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourcebundle) {
    makeDraggable(CallRequestTitledPane);
}

@FXML
private double x = 0, y = 0;

private Stage stage;

@FXML
private void makeDraggable(TitledPane pane) {
    pane.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
        x = event.getSceneX();
        y = event.getSceneY();
    });

    pane.setOnMouseDragged((event) -> {
        pane.setTranslateX(event.getScreenX() - x);
        pane.setTranslateY(event.getScreenY() - y);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `CallRequestTitledPane` the root node? You could always use `translateX` and `translateY` to move a node around. This doesn't resize the window though and parts of the node are simply cut of, if they move outside the window.

Comment: I've added an update to the above code.

Comment: @fabian I've changed the code to reflect a working solution. Thanks for the tip!